# How to extract the 2nd decimal number inside parentheses in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

could anyone can help me to take a look at this pd dataframe:

```
class_0                       class_1
(0, 0.021043771043771035)     (1, 0.021043771043771035)
```

How can i get a new table like this:

```
class_0                       class_1
0.021043771043771035          0.021043771043771035
```

Comment: Where are you stuck with this?  Plenty of tutorials show you how to make a new table from an existing one; plenty show you how to access a given element of a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since column has `tuple`s, you can extract them by indexing into it:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'a':((1,2), (3,4)), 'b': ((4,5), (10,11))}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

df  # output

       a       b
0   (1, 2)  (4, 5)
1   (3, 4)  (10, 11)
```

Extract elements from `tuple`:

```
df['a0'] = df['a'].str[0]
df['a1'] = df['a'].str[1]
```

Output:

```
      a        b      a0    a1
0   (1, 2)  (4, 5)     1    2
1   (3, 4)  (10, 11)   3    4
```

Or to replace df['a'] with 2nd tuple element:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I need to replace all the tuple inside the dataframe with its 2nd element? For example, replace (1, 2) with 2, (4, 5) with 5, (3, 4) with 4, (10, 11) with 11?

Comment: Thanks, I wrote a for loop to take care of it

Comment: updated my ans.